# How to calculate sample size for stratified sampling

Tags: sampling

When determining the size of a sample for each strata how should this be calculated? Do we compute the sample size based on the total population and then stratify based on the percentage of each strata or do we consider each strata as a different population and calculate the sample size individually?

Comment: It would really help if you described which kind of data you talk will have and which kind of test you are going to do to answer which question.

Comment: I have data with regard to fraudulent transactions in 5 cities. I want to know the overall mean of fraudulent case, but also the mean of individual cities to then run a hypothesis testing and compare the mean between the cities.

Comment: So you probably want to do a one way ANOVA across subjects with post hoc tests. I see no strong reason to stratify here. Just have enough samples per city (so that you have the power to detect effect sizes that interest you) and keep the sample size roughly equal for each city (which will help with the assumption of equal variances)

Comment: Even if the population size between the cities is very large?

Comment: Unless you are comparing a village of 500 with a metropolis yes. Let's say your smallest city has 25k inhabitants and the largest 1000k. If your sample is a couple of hundred per city, it will in all cases be very small compared to the total population. Random selection of sample points within each city is much more important than anything else.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for the explanation. As for determining the sample size, based on the confidence interval and standard error, should I calculate the sample size and divide by 5 cities or should I use the calculated sample for each?

Comment: Don't divide the sample size by 5. You need that sample size in each post hoc test to detect effect of the size you want to be able to detect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments reveal that you might have a different problem from what the question asks, but I'm going to answer the question you originally asked anyway in case someone else finds themself with the same query.

The sample size required for a design-based sampling scheme is a function of the size of the population, the variability of responses in the population, and the intended accuracy of the estimate. Stratification is meant to minimise sample size by grouping units into similar groups, decreasing the variability of responses within each group, and thus decreasing the required sample size across all groups.

Selection is then done independently within each stratum, and the estimates for each stratum are combined to come up with the estimate across the population. So effectively stratification involves designing a separate survey for each stratum - this means strata should be designed first. However, since allocation of sample between strata does have dependencies: you have a finite amount of money across all strata, and you have a target standard error for your combined estimate, etc; you need to optimise all sample sizes together.

The standard way to do this is to choose what you'd like to optimise (minimal sample size for a fixed standard error? minimal standard error for a fixed cost?), and then apply the [optimal allocation formula](http://stattrek.com/statistics/dictionary.aspx?definition=Optimum_allocation) (or other) across your strata. This formula requires setting a total sample size, however, if you have a target estimator variance, you can substitute the $n_h$ derived by the optimal formula into the variance formula for your estimator and find $n$ as a function of your target estimator variance. Then you can find all your $n_h$s.

After applying the optimal allocation if any samples are overallocated (i.e. you select more than the stratum population) or underallocated (i.e. you don't select enough units to be able to estimate variance within the stratum), you fix their sample sizes and re-run the allocation. Usually, you fix overallocated strata first, re-run allocation, then if any strata are still underallocated you bump up their sample size until it's good enough.

So, choose strata first, then find total sample size using the allocation formula and your constraints, then allocate this sample size and adjust.

Comment: Yes, it ends that the problem I have might not need stratified sampling but your answer will be very useful when I will need to stratify. Just wanted to make sure to understand the steps: 1) choose strata 2) calculate sample size for each stratum based on constraint 3) use optimum allocation formula to adjust size of each stratum 4) refine sample size of each stratum if needed, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that'll be the general guide. If you run into difficulties in the specifics, just ask another question here!